What is the legal justification for education staff and/or accompanying police forcing entry to dwellings in the case of truancy?
There is a news article about the crackdown on non-attendance at school.  It includes the statement:

Parents have told us about very strict schools actually forcing entry to their homes. Schools are turning up with community police.

Without proper legal justification forcing entry into someones home is a serious violent crime.  Citizens advice have a page that lists situations where police are allowed to do this, it talks about a search warrant and various "emergency" type situations that do not appear to apply here.  The is also the court service rules on forced entry, but those are even less likely to apply.
Is there a likely legal justification for such a forced entry?

There's one article, quoting one person claiming what some other people told them, in likely imprecise language. I doubt "strict schools [are] actually forcing entry to their homes". There may well be cases of police visiting homes - it's part of their job.

Even the story's headline isn't quite what the article says. They seem to be using hearsay from a very few cases to show that schools are being heavy handed about absenteeism. Perhaps they are, but the shock-horror reporting is from The Observer, which is The Guardian's Sunday edition.

Easy, it didn’t happen
There is a hierarchy of truth, it goes:

True enough for the physical sciences
True enough for the law
True enough for the social sciences
True enough for the humanities
True enough for journalism
True enough for politics.

Don’t believe what a journalist quotes an activist source says unnamed “parents” said. In a court, that’s called hearsay of hearsay and is doubly inadmissible.
